# Clarifications about pointers use

Tags: c, pointers

I have a question for the exact meaning of a pointers phrase.

I have the following method:

```
myFunc(const void * p)
{
  ...
}
```

And it is being called by:

```
myStruct *st;
...
myFunc((char **)&st->arr);
```

I have experience with pointers, but in this case I still get lost with all these pointers and casting..
Can I get please an accurate explanation about how this case works?

Thanks

Comment: it's not working if you call your function without the cast ?

Comment: It would help to see the definition of `myStruct` and what `myFunc` does with the pointer passed into it.

Comment: [See this too](http://boredzo.org/pointers/)

Comment: This typecast is wrong, don't use this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seams to be bad quality code! Maybe not dangerous, as `const` appears in prototype.

`myFunc(const void * p)` accepts a pointer to anything and `const` should mean it won't touch it.

Now, `st` is a pointer to `myStruct`, so `st->arr` is the value of `arr` member and `&st->arr` is memory address of `arr` member. Assuming `arr` is an array, `st->arr` value is already a pointer.

So, `(char**)` is possibly the correct type of `&st->arr`, it is a pointer to a character array. And if it is the correct type, there is no need to cast!

You cast when you need to tell the compiler to handle your data as another data. It would make sense, in this case `myFunc((const void *)&st->arr);`

Anyway, without further information on myFunc, I belive that true programmer intention was `myFunc((const void *) st->arr);`

Answer (score 0):

the address of st->arr is being converted to a char** (i.e. the address where to find a pointer to a char). myFunc accepts pretty much anything (void*) and you must be careful to pass it something it knows how to handle.

Internally, myFunc can do something like this:

```
struct myStruct{
    char* arr;
};

void myFunc(const void* ptr){
    char** cPtr = (char**) ptr;
    (*cPtr)[1] = ...;
}

int main()
{
    struct myStruct s;
    ...

    myFunc((char **)&s.arr);

    ...
}
```

However, you should notice that this is extremely bad (as in "dangerouse") code.

Comment: You are mixing C++ in a C topic.

Comment: thanks, it was only for simplicity in writing the example though

Comment: And note there's a `const`, so `(char**) ptr;` is pottencialy dangerous!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method myFunc with a double pointer **char **** and the same you are catching with the  **const void *ptr** . In C a void pointer can hold the other pointer types like(char */float */int */...), later on we can typecast them when we are using.

So here a void pointer can able to hold a double character pointer and you can typecast the void pointer to a double character pointer later on like

```
    char **tempPtr = (char **)p;
```

Here const qualifier makes the pointer p as a constant data pointer, which means inside the function it wont change the data it is pointing to.